# How to change the existing div value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page which shows a particular div like this,

```
<div id="placeholder1" style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

but on some click I want to change my div dynamically to something like this.

```
<div id="placeholder2" style="height: 150px;"></div>
```

How to do it?

Comment: The only difference between the two is the `id` ... are you wanting to actually change the div's id, or just change which div is currently visible on the page?

Comment: I want to change the div which is visible on the page....

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that you want to change which div is visible on the page, not just change properties of a single div.

Comment: Don't change ID's, rather change classes. Things will get really messed up in your CSS and JS when you start changing ID's around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're into jQuery, you can bind a click event to whatever element and change it like so (make sure the DOM has finished loading first):

```
$(function() { 
  $('#click_me_to_change_id').bind('click', function() {
    $('#placeholder1').attr('id', 'placeholder2');
  });
});
```

**Edit**: Upon inspection I realize you want to hide/show differing divs, try this out:

```
$(function() { 
  $('#click_me_to_toggle_visible_div').bind('click', function() {
    $('#placeholder1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#placeholder2').css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

Comment: On the other hand, if you're not into jQuery, you should be.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I'm seeing is the ID. If so...

```
document.getElementById('placeholder1').id = 'placeholder2';
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has an onclick event handler to detect clicks, and getElementById to identify elements by ID.
if you want to change the ID just use:

```
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder1');
div.onclick = function(){
    div.id = 'placeholder2';
}
```

to change which is displayed, assuming you have the html:

```
<div id="placeholder1" style="height: 150px;"></div>
<div id="placeholder2" style="height: 150px;display:none"></div>
```

you would use

```
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('placeholder2');
div.onclick = function(){
    div.style.display = 'none';
    div2.style.display = 'block';
}
```